# Decoding mmap() flags on Linux

Tags: linux, mmap

I am reverse engineering an ELF binary and in the assembly, I can see that mmap() was invoked with the flags parameter set to 0x22.

How can I decode what this flag represents?

As per: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html, the flags value can be formed by performing an OR operation between the flags.

so, 0x22 could be as shown below:

```
0x20 || 0x2
```

By looking up the header files on Linux, I think, it should be: MAP_PRIVATE || MAP_ANONYMOUS

Is that correct?

There are some other flags mentioned in the header file as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have to use bitwise-OR not logical-OR, so

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
```

Then later in the `flags` argument to the `mmap` syscall, this value is what you appear to want:

```
(MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS)
```

If you run a binary under the `strace` program, it will show you the symbolic values used for syscall args. That’s the easiest way to decode those sorts of arguments.